# dart: for the syntax gurus, how to exchange subtree in nested class

Tags: class, dictionary, dart, syntax, nested

I know how to neatly replace a single element of a list with

```dart
myDataList = myDataList.map((dataItem) {
        return dataItem.id == event.id ? 
          event.dataUpdatedItem 
        : 
          dataItem;
      }).toList();
```

In my case, dataItem is a nested class like `List<Person> person` and I only want to update `person.address` of `person.id == event.id`. My `event.dataUpdatedItem` is of type `Address` and the `event.id` points to `person.id`.

You guys frequently provide me brain teasers with your nifty expressions that compress a page of code into a 2-liner. Is this also possible here with a wrapping list around the class, holding the nested class to be updated?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have some way to create a new person with the new address, so let's assume it's a [`built_value`](https://pub.dev/packages/built_value).

```dart
person = [for (var p in person) 
  if (p.id == event.id) p.rebuild((b) => b..address = event.dataUpdatedItem) 
  else p];
```

If the `Person.address` can be updated directly, you don't need to replace the entire list, so:

```dart
person.firstWhere((p) => p.id == event.id).address = event.dataUpdatedItem;
```

Comment: and you even compressed it into a single line. The latter was my use case. When I see it, it looks so easy - slowly I am getting into this :-)